# Excel formula to combine first names

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to figure out a formula or set of formulas to pull two first names in a cell. For example, the data in one cell will may have either "Jess Staley & Adam Fernandez" or "Jess & Adam Fernandez", and I'm trying to get a formula to pull in "Jess & Adam". I've got the formula to pull the first name but can't pull the second name after the &. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the formula you have so far? Also, what happens if you have **Peggy Sue Smith & David Allan Brown**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array form of TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" & ",TRUE,LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:$A$10)-1)*99+1,99)),FIND(" ",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:$A$10)-1)*99+1,99))&" ")-1))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced in Office 365 Excel.

[image]

The formula splits on the `&` by creating a large white space to land on then looping trough each section and trimming the results.

We then find the first space in each section and return the first word to the left of the first space.

This will only return the first word in each section, so `Peggy Sue Smith` will become `Peggy` not `Peggy Sue`

---

Now if you can guarantee that there will only be two names then you can use this formula regardless of version:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" ")-1) & IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("&",A1))," & " & LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)),FIND(" ",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))&" ")-1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: .....................beautiful formula.....................

Comment: Wow.....you totally made my day!! It works perfectly!!